# UiCollectionView - to load image from a url

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Im trying to create UicollectionView and to load images in that cell . Im getting only the cell and not the images.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad    
{
   [super viewDidLoad];  
   self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height)collectionViewLayout:layout];
;
    [collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:collectionView];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 8;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = @"cookcell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

   if (!cell) { 
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
   }

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img.auctiva.com/imgdata/1/2/8/3/1/8/7/webimg/611377020_tp.jpg"];

   NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
   UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

   cell.imageView.image = tmpImage ;
   return  cell;;  
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

   return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    return CGSizeMake(80, 80);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Add imageView at collection view's datasource method `cellForItemAt `

Comment: You cannot add like this     [collectionView addSubview:_imageView];

Comment: what you tried and where you want to show the image  in collectionview.

Comment: @anbu-karthik : Need to show images loaded from an url in collectionView

Answer (score 0):

- Confirm delegate for datasource and delegate for collectionView to the viewController wherever you are using it.
- In delegate we have cellForRowAtIndex same as UITableView.
- Get the cell in that function respective to indexpath.
- Assign image to that cell, (Cell should have the UIImageView). If you want static image you can assign directly to the respective cell class else in delegate method for every indexpath.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code, its good that you have set datasource protocol for collection view, but thats not the way to load images from url. You have to implement the following datasource protocol methods as of swift 3.

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

```
 return datalistArr.count
```

}

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collecionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell           
    cell.imageViewIncell.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: imageurl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholderImage"))
    return cell
}
```

If you have used Alamofire it has extension of UIImageView which loads image from url very easily as in example, cell.imageViewIncell.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: imageurl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholderImage"))

Answer (score 0):

You need to set image in cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"receipeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img.auctiva.com/imgdata/1/2/8/3/1/8/7/webimg/611377020_tp.jpg"];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    cell.imageView.image = tmpImage ;

    return  cell;;

}
```

Comment: cell.imageView.image = tmpImage ;  -   in this line property imageView is not in collectionViewcell

Comment: it is the default imageview not custom cell imageview.. you need to replace this imageview with your imageview .

Comment: This will block the UI till the image is downloaded rom URL. Not an acceptable answer

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageURl.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let imageview:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    do {
        let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(string: "your URL")!)
        let img = UIImage.init(data: data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            imageview.image = img
            cell.contentView.addSubview(imageview)
        }
    } catch let erroer {
        print(erroer.localizedDescription)
    }
    //If you load image using api use cache-policy or pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0'. 
    //imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "your URL"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""your placeholder image""))
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize.init(width: 200, height: 200)
}
```

> This simple way to display image using URL.